# Delphi: Property with combobox editor in Object Inspector. Get Form components in a list

Tags: delphi, components

I want to edit published property in the Object Inspector via dropdown list.
Let's say it's  `DataSet: TDataSet`.

I'm not started yet, but using this http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc092501c.htm I will create a property editor and in `GetValues` method I should do some job to find out which components, that are descendats of `TDataSet`, are already on the Form that I'm designing now.

Yet didn't find any examples of it. How should I provide access to the current form inside my `PropertyEditor.GetValues` method or there is another approach?

**Why it is NOT this:** [How to create a component property that lists other components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159744/how-to-create-a-component-property-that-lists-other-components)

Because at certain times in a drop-down list should be listed components of two or more types. At last - I need to hold in the Property a pointer to certain component, which would be not the same type, as it is declared.

I repeat: `Property: TClassNone` and shoud be listed there: `TClassOne, TClassTwo and TClass Three`, which are **not** descendatns of `TClassNone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was too hasty in writing the original answer. Here's an edit:

Write a descendant of `TComponentProperty` and override `GetValues`. Have a look at the `TInterfaceProperty` implementation in `DesignEditors` which filters the selection only to instances of components supporting the interface assignable to the property.

Comment: Oh that's it! I will do it right now and report back. Any other suggestions are welcome. Not yet clearly see what I actually should do. But already found `GetProperties` and working on it in blind ;)

Comment: I suppose that I should override `GetSelections`? Am I right or I should look deeper?

Comment: Just figured out, that _GetProperties   Should be overridden to call PropertyProc for every sub-property (or nested property) of the property begin edited and passing a new TPropertyEdtior for each sub-property.  By default, PropertyProc is not called and no sub-properties are assumed.  TClassProperty will pass a new property editor for each published property in a class.  TSetProperty passes a new editor for each element in the set._ I guess this is not the thing I need. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: This works out! I did as you suggested by looking upon `TInterfaceProperty` in `DesignEditors` unit. Just have copied the code for `GetValues` and `RecieveComponentNames` and instead of code `Supports(...)` in last one proc, I've inserted `and (Temp.InheritsFrom(X) or Temp.InheritsFrom(Y))`. Now only left changes, that should be made on changing the property with a certain component. Is there any event, where I can test the assigning component's type? Or better to create  another question?

Comment: Please, refer to the [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544367/delphi-override-an-assignment-proc-for-components-property-in-object-inspector) for further discussion of last topic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Depends on what you need. Perhaps you could use the setter method for the property.

Comment: If this is possible to you, I have made a new question and it's here: [link ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544367/delphi-override-an-assignment-proc-for-components-property-in-object-inspector). I did my best to explain. And setter method doen't fit well as I see.

Answer (score 5):

All I think you need to do is make it a published property of your component and let Delphi's default property editor do its work:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  ...
  published
    property DataSet: TDataSet read GetDataSet write SetDataSet;
  end;
```

For example, I think TDataSource works like this without registering any special property editor for it.

Comment: thanks. But I need to be more complex. That's why I said `Let's say it's DataSet: TDataSet` - I mean i.e. - in example. Ofcourse this can be something else as I'm writing a new component.

Comment: This should work automatically for published properties of any TComponent descendant type.

Comment: Well, try it: don't write any property editor, just publish a property on your component. Register your component and try it in the IDE.

Comment: well, I suppose. But you know - if you have `Images` property is would search for `TImageList` in this module and other related on dropdown. As well as if you have `DataSet` property IDE would search and list all `TDataSet` and its descendants in the module and related ones. If I need to put a value into a property `MyBrandNewClass: TMyBrandNewClass` - I need to search all the descendants of `TMyBrandNewClass` in the module. And I'm looking for a method to do that. Hope this is clear now. But thanks.

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying the IDE will do this automatically, there's no need for a special property editor. Assuming your TMyBrandNewClass is a descendant of TComponent.

Comment: Okay. Let's make it more complex. At a certain times MyBrandNewClass property should grab components in it's list, that are of `TThisClass` and `TOtherClass`. And both of them are only descendants of `TComponent`, and I want MyBrandNewClass property to show me components only of these two classes. How would IDE do that automatically?

Comment: That's a different question, and I posted a different answer.