# Delphi: override an assignment proc for components property in Object Inspector

Tags: forms, delphi, ide, vcl

I have a component i.e. `TBrandNewComponent`, who has published property `Jumbo: TJumboClass`, which is:

```
TJumboClass = class
   P: Pointer
end;
```

I had overriden the `GetValues` procedure to show different components in a list of `Jumbos`'s values in Object Inspector. Now list shows components of `TJumboClass` and components of `TMassiveClass` and `TRotefulClass`.

There is also `TBrandNewComponent.JumboSelectedComponentType: integer`, which I want to change due to selected component in `TBrandNewComponent.Jumbo` and also I want **something-like** *cast* `TMassiveClass` and `TRotefulClass` to `TJumboClass` saving them something like that: `TJumboClass.P = Pointer(TMassiveClass(current))`.

By that I mean, that I need to store to a property `TBrandNewComponent.JumboClass.P` a pointer of appropriate selected component, so that with a `JumboSelectedComponentType` I can correctly access this pointer and return the right class in further operations.

**So, is there any procedure, that affects that and is that possible anyway?**

Any suggestions and thoughts are appreciated!

PS: I've already discovered method `SetValue`. Now I need somehow to override it. What it might be?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to try casting classes to another that's different. What it sounds like you're trying to do will lead to memory overwrites and access violations - don't do it. It seems to me you have a problem **(A)** and you've come up with an idea **(B)** that if you can get it working, might solve your problem. Unfortunately **(B)** as you've described it is unclear, dangerous; and probably unlikely to work at all. I suggest you rather tell us about your root problem: **(A)**. You'll get much better help that way.

Comment: I think there is no such dangerous problem about that as you say. I need to combine different classes into one to have opportunity to switch between them at design-time. Like, for example, people do to unite DB-components (sdac, ado, bde etc) to develop one app and than only switch the modules. All I want - do the same, but also get able to do it in design-time on the form. Yes, this is huge thing to write many `cases`, but still I would like to implement such a thing. Was I clear? By `casting` I mean that I can get a pointer, which I would use further in appropriate way.

Comment: To clarify more: if you have `TConnectionA, TDataSetA` and `TConnectionB,TDataSetB` and both have different ancestors - the only way to combine them - is third party. (I mean in terms of published properties, that are shown in Object Inspector - only this is the problem).

Comment: To me it sounds like a problem that can be solved with proper inheritance and the use of the strategy pattern.

Comment: Are TMassiveClass and TRotefulClass classes you are developing? If so,  maybe you should have them implement a common interface and reference that.

Comment: The usual letters used to describe that situation are *X* and *Y*, @Craig, giving rise to the term [*XY problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/33732).

Comment: @Frazz - well, those two are developed before me. That's why the problem is. But thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe makes no sense.

If you derive `TMassiveClass` and `TRotefulClass` from `TJumboClass` then the Object Inspector will automatically list all component instances of those class types for you, there is no need to write a custom design-time editor to override `GetValues()`, the default implementation is sufficient.

```
type
  TBrandNewComponent = class(...)
  private
    fJumbo: TJumboClass;
  published
    property Jumbo: TJumboClass read fJumbo write fJumbo;
  end;
```

```
type
  TMassiveClass = class(TJumboClass)
    ...
  end;

  TRotefulClass = class(TJumboClass)
    ...
  end;
```

If you do not derive `TMassiveClass` and `TRotefulClass` from `TJumboClass` but still want the Object Inspector to automatically list all component instances of those class types for you, you can use a custom `IInterface` for that purpose (yes, you can use interfaces in `published` properties):

```
type
  IJumbo = interface(IInterface)
  ['{DA51630E-2FFB-425D-A62D-F1BE414DBC6F}']
  end;

  TBrandNewComponent = class(...)
  private
    fJumbo: IJumbo;
  published
    property Jumbo: IJumbo read fJumbo write fJumbo;
  end;
```

```
type
  TJumboClass = class(..., IJumbo)
    ...
  end;

  TMassiveClass = class(..., IJumbo)
    ...
  end;

  TRotefulClass = class(..., IJumbo)
    ...
  end;
```

Either way, to update the value of `TBrandNewComponent.JumboSelectedComponentType` whenever `TBrandNewComponent.Jumbo` is changed, you can provide a setter method for the `Jumbo` property, which will be called at both run-time and design-time.  Again, no custom design-time editor is needed:

```
type
  TBrandNewComponent = class(...)
  private
    fJumbo: TJumboClass;
    procedure SetJumbo(Value: TJumboClass);
  published
    property Jumbo: TJumboClass read fJumbo write SetJumbo;
  end;

procedure TBrandNewComponent.SetJumbo(Value: TJumboClass);
begin
  if fJumbo <> Value then
  begin
    fJumbo := Value;
    // update JumboSelectedComponentType as needed...
end;
```

Your description of `JumboClass.P` really does not make sense.  Assuming `current` is the component object currently assigned to the `Jumbo` property, then you are essentially setting `Jumbo.P` to the `Self` pointer of the component object, which is basically useless.

Since your other property is named `JumboSelectedComponentType`, it *sounds* like you want to store the **class type** of the selected component, not the **object pointer**.  If that is the case, then a much more robust design is to give the `JumboSelectedComponentType` property a getter method (or just change it into a public function instead of a property) that queries the current `Jumbo` object for its `ClassType`:

```
type
  TBrandNewComponent = class(...)
  private
    fJumbo: TJumboClass;
  public
    function JumboSelectedComponentType: TClass;
  published
    property Jumbo: TJumboClass read fJumbo write fJumbo;
  end;

function TBrandNewComponent.JumboSelectedComponentType: TClass;
begin
  if fJumbo <> nil then
    Result := fJumbo.ClassType
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TJumboClassType = class of TJumboClass;

  TBrandNewComponent = class(...)
  private
    fJumbo: TJumboClass;
  public
    function JumboSelectedComponentType: TJumboClassType;
  published
    property Jumbo: TJumboClass read fJumbo write fJumbo;
  end;

function TBrandNewComponent.JumboSelectedComponentType: TJumboClassType;
begin
  if fJumbo <> nil then
    Result := TJumboClassType(fJumbo.ClassType)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

If this is NOT what you are looking for, then you need to provide more details about what exactly you are really looking for, because your original description is just too vague.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. An idea about using interfaces seems brilliant and I wish it helps, but I think it would be too hard for `TMassiveClass` and `TRotefulClass` to "interface" them as they are some kind of base classes with visual components. Like `TQuery` or `TADOStoredProc` or `TAstaDataSet`. As you can see - it would be a work for total recreation and recompiling of all DB or other visual components (visual in design-time I mean). Not so easy. A simple example what I need goes next.

Comment: You can think of a `Connection` property of components such as `TQuery`, `TADOQuery`, `TMSQuery` etc. All this type components should have a `Connection` prop. But each component refer to its own Connection-type-class. And I need to write a component, which can hold all of these packages. And for that reason, I would need to create custom Connection property, which can hold and translate any of available Connection-type-classes. Because not all of these packages have same ancestor - I need this solution. Do you think its possible anyway without recompiling packages?

Comment: For a better clarity: I need to create a component (i.e. `TMyQuery`) which has a Connection property and can read `TConnection`, `TMSConnection`, `TADOConnection`, `TMyConnection` etc (whatever dropped on the form in design-time). And depending on selected connection it should produce certain according dataset-class. Guess this more clear now.

Comment: Custom database connection components should derive from `TCustomConnection`.  If you derive `TMyConnection` from `TCustomConnection`, and then declare your `Connection` property as `TCustomConnection`, the OI's default property editor will show you all available `TCustomConnection`-derived components.

Comment: There is no ready way to dynamically know which `TDataSet` class to use for any given `TCustomConnection`-derived class, so you may have to hard-code that logic for specific types. Or *maybe* you can use RTTI to discover the `Connection`'s source unit and then enumerate that unit's classes looking for a `TDataSet` descendant.